# overtaking scenario how can i make one car over take another?

Tags: netlogo

in the case of two lanes on a road, in real life you can only over taking by moving from the outside lane to the inside lane then once the car is passed return to the outside lane, in the case of net logo i have it set out that a car will check the patch set in front and to the left of them to see if there is another car, as seen in this section of coding if there is no car in the set the car remains driving, if there is another car the car will decelerate or if the car in front has stopped then the car will stop.

My problem is i have defined a patch set to check called "on-left" i want the car to move to the other lane when a car is in front as long as there is no cars in the on-left patch set, and also if the car is in the inside lane and there is no car in a similar patch set to on left but for the right, for the car to move back into the outside lane.

i have tried with this coding but for some reason the cars don't overtake and occasionally occupy the same space i'm not sure if i'm using the ifelse statement wrong, **how can i make one car over take another?**

```
to control-speed01
let in-lane (patch-set patch-ahead 2 patch-ahead 1 )
let car01-ahead one-of cars01-on in-lane
let on-left (patch-set patch-left-and-ahead 90 1 patch-left-and-ahead 45 1.5 patch-left-and-ahead 135 1.5)
let on-right (patch-set patch-right-and-ahead 90 1 patch-right-and-ahead 45 1.5 patch-right-and-ahead 135 1.5)

ifelse car01-ahead = nobody  [
ifelse speed < maxSpeed [set speed speed + acceleration] [set speed speed - deceleration]
]
[

ifelse [speed] of car01-ahead = 0 [ifelse turtles-on on-left = nobody  [move-to patch-left-and-ahead 90 1][set speed 0]][
  ifelse [speed] of car01-ahead >= maxSpeed [
    set speed maxSpeed
    set speed speed - deceleration
   ][
 set speed speed
   ]]

  ifelse [speed] of car01-ahead = 0 [ifelse turtles-on on-right = nobody  [move-to patch-right-and-ahead 90 1][set speed 0]][
  ifelse [speed] of car01-ahead >= maxSpeed [
      set speed maxSpeed
    set speed speed - deceleration
  ] [
set speed speed
]]]

end
```

Comment: This is very similar to your newer question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49709206/how-to-overtake-in-a-two-lane-scenario . I've answered there... I assume you don't need help here anymore.